# How can I read a large file (A gig or more) in lua?

Tags: file, memory, lua

I have been searching for the answer to this and everyone's answer is always just do it line by line, but the thing is my file is all just one line of characters, and trying to io.open("file.txt", "rb"):read("*a") results in a memory error. I can not think of how to load it in part at a time because like I said, its all one giant line.

Comment: How about using `:read(4096)` or similar to read in fixed-size chunks?

Comment: Does that basically work the same as string.sub but for reading files, if so thats exactly what I needed.

Comment: Not same, as it reads sequentially by itself. Working in tandem with `:seek("set", start)`, you can do the same thing with a file that you'd do with `.sub` on a string.

Comment: In *any* programming language, what you've got to do here is to first `seek` to some location in the file, then `read` a certain number of *bytes.* The data is not considered to be "a string," *per se,* but simply a blob of bytes. (Lua, as far as I recall, does not support the notion of "memory-mapped files.")

Comment: Can you give me an example, like lets assume the file is 1,000 characters long (Its not, its much longer, thats why I need to use this) How can I grab only characters 500 to 750

Comment: seek to 499 (offsets in files counts from 0) and read 250 bytes

Answer (score 3):

You can use `io.read(size)` to read a buffer of a specified size (as is already discussed in comments). See the [example at the end of the I/O section](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html) in [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html).

Since you are doing a search in the chunks you read, the string you are searching for may be split between different chunks, so you need to take that into account. [Another example from PiL that talks about reading large files](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.1.html) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

you could use table as buffer:

```
function readFile(file)
local t = {}
 for line in io.lines(file) do
    t[#t + 1] = line .. "\n"
end
  local s = table.concat(t)
  return s
end
```